# How do I get values from table in JSP?

Tags: jsp, ms-access

I am working on a project and I got a problem. I am using JSP and MS-Access.
I have a table and I want to get it values as follows:

This is table:

```
Service    Charges           <br/>
  Cons     200               <br/>
  Cons     500               <br/>
  inj      300               <br/>
  inj      200               <br/>
  cons     400               <br/>
  inj      800               <br/>
```

Like this I want to get in JSP:

```
 cons    inj     <br/>
 200     300     <br/>
 500     200     <br/>
 400     800     <br/>
```

I want to sort out these two in a column. I do I get it in JSP.

Comment: You definitely should switch to a real database. For starters: You would need to have Access running on your webserver.

Comment: how? I tried but nothing happened.

Comment: "Access running on your webserver" is a nonsensical statement. There is no server-side process involved with an Access/Jet/ACE data file at all, and you don't have to have Access installed, since the Jet database engine is installed on every copy of Windows beginning with Windows 2000. I would agree that Access/Jet/ACE is not an appropriate data store for use on a web application, but the reasons for that have nothing to do with @nfechner's erroneous comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a very general question and hard to cover in a 5-line answer. Data access and retrieval is a fundamental cornerstone of software development. I would suggest you start reading up a bit on [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) to understand the underlying Java standard for database connectivity.

If you want to go further, then you could move on to something like [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html), which is a popular framework for facilitating JDBC operations. Or look at so called ORM (Object Relational Mapping) frameworks that map between normalized relation database models and JAva object models. [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is a fairly popular ORM framework.

Also (like someone mentioned in a comment), you should really drop MS Access. It's not a "real" database and it's definitely not suited for server applications. MySql would be much more suited.

Comment: Hi, I don't know MySQL, but I want to switch over to the ORACLE. But uptill to switch over I have to work with MS -ACCESS. In my above question if there are even number of rows like for inj 4 and for cons 5. Then the last row won't remain blank for inj as it is in a loop it prints the last retrieved value. How can I deal with this?